# C# Marshalling char** and unsigned char**

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport

Here is the problem - i have some C image processing library that i need to use from C# application. Lack of experience with DllImport strikes me hard for now.

The function i need to use looks like:

```
    IMAGEPROCESS_API const int importImage
        (
        const unsigned char* image,
        const char* xmlInput,
        unsigned char** resultImage,
        char** xmlOutput
        );
```

So, it accepts raw image data, xml containing parameters and image width'height and then return processed image and some xml report.

For now im trying to approach it like this:

```
 [DllImport("imageprocess.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,EntryPoint = "importImage",CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int ImportImageNative(IntPtr imageData, String xmlDescriptor, out IntPtr processedImage, out IntPtr xmlOut);
```

but without any success.

Any suggestions how should it be done?

Edit:
still no luck ((
done it by messy C++ CLI for now

Comment: Could you provide more details on "without any success"?

Comment: Oh, it compiles and runs but encounters access violation, so something is really wrong. I've double-checked input xml, so i believe problem is with output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the output parameters, you should access the returned data using [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx).

Since the original memory was allocated within the unmanaged API, it's still your responsibility to free it as appropriate.

I also think that you should use `String` on both the first two parameters, not sure why the first one is an `IntPtr`?

Comment: Because i get an IntPtr immediately by System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetHBitamp();

Comment: @ALOR - I see, this is not a C-string then and you have it right.  That's `Bitmap` not `Bitamp` I think?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    [DllImport("imageprocess.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int importImage(string imageData, string xmlDescriptor, out string processedImage, out string xmlOut);
```

Comment: Ok, but how should i 'cast' byte[] to string and vice versa?

Comment: OK means it worked (as in - not crashed) ? What byte[] are you referring to? The signature you posted has only char arrays / pointers