# Debugging DLLImport in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, pinvoke, dllimport

I have been attempting to get the [MySQL Embedded Library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/libmysqld.html) working in my C# application for the past 12 hours or so, and have been stuck for quite some time. I am getting the following error when I call `mysql_server_init()`...

> Unhandled Exception: System.AcessViolationException: Attempted to read
>   or write protected memory.

The C++ method takes an `int` and two `char**` as parameters, but I was told a null terminated `string[]` array would suffice in C#. As this is the first method that you're supposed to call, I am somewhat at a loss as to this issue.

Here's my code...

```
public class MySQLServer
{
    [DllImport("libmysqld.dll")]
    static extern int mysql_server_init(int argc, string[] argv, string[] groups);

    [DllImport("libmysqld.dll")]
    static extern void mysql_server_end();

    public static bool Start()
    {
        string[] argv = new string[3];
        argv[0] = "mysql_test";
        argv[1] = "--datadir=C:/MYSQLTEST";
        argv[2] = null;

        string[] groups = new string[3];
        groups[0] = "libmysqd_server";
        groups[1] = "libmysqd_client";
        groups[2] = null;

        int res;

        if ((res = mysql_server_init(3, argv, groups)) == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Init Failed with error code: %d", res);
            return false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Started Successfully!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, in your comment in @Mitch's thread, you state that it makes a local copy. It doesn't. It keeps a reference to it. But MySql doesn't know anything about C# garbage collecting, so _after_ the method returns, your program crashes. See: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/758543-calling-dll-function-c-char-parameter-type (quite down the thread)

Comment: I have to ask the reason you cannot use the following: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net.html

Comment: You can always modify and compile the library yourself.

Comment: It was my understanding that didn't work for the MySQL Embedded Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have a tiny error, causing `mysql_server_init` to read beyond the array boundaries. Replace `3` with `2` and remove the third array entry. The default marshaler will do the rest.

```
public static bool Start()
{
    string[] argv = new string[3];
    argv[0] = "mysql_test";
    argv[1] = "--datadir=C:/MYSQLTEST";

    string[] groups = new string[3];
    groups[0] = "libmysqd_server";
    groups[1] = "libmysqd_client";

    int res;

    if ((res = mysql_server_init(2, argv, groups)) == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Init Failed with error code: %d", res);
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Update

From [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/758543-calling-dll-function-c-char-parameter-type), you should not use `mysql_server_init` at all, but `mysql_library_init` instead:

> 1. Both 'argv' and 'groups' are stored by the library and used later. This is a serious problem, because if you use P/Invoke marshaling, the
>      pointers that .NET passes to the function will become invalid as soon
>      as the function returns. When the library later tries to refer to argv
>      or groups, it'll find nothing but garbage there, causing unexpected
>      behavior or a crash.
>
> If you're using MySQL 5.0.3 or later, try using mysql_library_init
>   instead - it makes an internal copy of argv and groups, so you can
>   keep using P/Invoke marshaling with no trouble (as long as you add a
>   null entry to the end of groups). Otherwise, you'll have to allocate
>   the memory yourself for the arrays and each string, to make sure the
>   pointers stay valid as long as your program is running.

So, if you *can* switch to using `mysql_library_init`, I'd suggest doing so. By-hand marshaling is not a trivial undertaking (but not too hard either).

Comment: You need to fix the size of the string array its currently 3 so the last element in the array will be null by default ( which is what he currently has ).

Comment: The reason I am not using mysql_library_init is the functions aren't exported. I didn't realize that the internal copies were only made by mysql_library_init though, I thought both did it in 5.0.3 and later.

Comment: @BrettPowell, so you cannot use mysql_library_init? Then we're off to a nice by-hand marshaling...

Comment: Actually, I just added a bunch of Console.ReadLine() lines and I can see it is printing something out to console now, but it closes way too fast. ReadLine() doesn't seem to be keeping it open after I call mysql_server_init(), is there any way else to so that I can read what it says?

Comment: @Brett does it help if you place breakpoint just after your call? Normally, you can catch all Console output by going to Options Dialog -> Debugging -> Check the "Redirect All Output Window Text to the Immediate Window".

Comment: That didn't work, but I was able to screenshot it in that split second (impressed myself). This is what I have now (http://oi55.tinypic.com/akd1ee.jpg), but I can go back to Google searching for this as I recall seeing something a few hours ago similar to this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Brett: I tried your code, and I receive your error. When I run two arguments, as described above, I do not receive your error anymore, the app stays stable (but mysql_server_init itself returns an error, which reminds me: `res` does _not_ contain the error code, use `GetLastError()` instead, plus, you should test the result for non-zero, instead of one).

Answer (score 2):

If the strings are being read from, you should be able to pass as an array of strings.

If they are being written to, then you will have to declare the parameters as `IntPtrs`, allocate the memory for them, and then marshal the data yourself (plus you will need to unallocate the memory as well).

what happens if you call like so (argc := 2):

```
    if ((res = mysql_server_init(2, argv, groups)) == 1) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Init Failed with error code: %d", res); 
        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: According to the documentation, it just reads the data from the array of strings and saves it locally so that they can be destroyed. As it is only reading them, I have no idea why I would be getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

> The C++ method takes an int and two char** as parameters, but I was
>   told a null terminated string[] array would suffice in C#. As this is
>   the first method that your supposed to call, I am at somewhat of a
>   loss as to the issue.

Who exactly told you this?

I do believe you could just use a reference to a **char[]**

> [DllImport("libmysqld.dll")]  static extern int mysql_server_init(int
>   argc, ref char[] argv, ref char[] groups);

Be sure the calling convention matches otherwise you will run into issues.

Mitch Wheat's answer can be enchanced by this thread: [Marshalling a char** in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591461/marshalling-a-char-in-c-sharp)

Some Additional Information: [C# Marshalling char** and unsigned char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008669/c-sharp-marshalling-char-and-unsigned-char)