# Debugging DLLImport in C# pt. 2

Tags: c#, mysql, interop, pinvoke, embedded-database

I am using the MySQL Embedded Library and using P/Invoke to call the necessary functions to start the server. We resolved some issues regarding it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822686/debugging-dllimport-in-c-sharp) topic, however another issue has presented itself.

The mysql_server_init() function returns 0 if success, 1 if error. Unfortunately, in my code when it returns 1, and I use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() the error code is 0. I am assuming that it is not picking up on the error being generated by mysql_server_init(), but I am at a loss as to how to find out where the problem is.

Here is the relevant code block...

```
    [DllImportAttribute("libmysqld.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int mysql_server_init(int argc, string[] argv, string[] groups);

    static string[] server_options = new string[2];
    static string[] server_groups = new string[3];

    public static bool Start()
    {
        server_options[0] = "mysql_test"; // not used?
        server_options[1] = "--defaults-file=./my.ini";

        server_groups[0] = "client";
        server_groups[1] = "server";
        server_groups[2] = "\0";

        if (mysql_server_init(2, server_options, server_groups) != 0)
        {
            int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Init Failed with error code: " + lastError);
            return false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Started Successfully!");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does mysql_server_init call SetLastError()? I see no indication that it does in the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-server-init.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mysql_server_init` function does not report errors via the Win32 error reporting mechanism `SetLastError()` and `GetLastError()`. So, you can"t use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to obtain the last error. The embedded mysql database reports errors via the functions `mysql_error()` and `mysql_errno()`. However, those functions seem to only report errors **AFTER** a successful call to `mysql_server_init()`.

I think the problem of your code lies in the way you terminate your server_groups array.
You should use "null" instead of "\0" to "terminate" your array:

```
public static bool Start() 
{ 
    server_options[0] = "mysql_test"; // not used? 
    server_options[1] = "--defaults-file=./my.ini"; 

    server_groups[0] = "client"; 
    server_groups[1] = "server"; 
    server_groups[2] = null; 

    if (mysql_server_init(2, server_options, server_groups) != 0) 
    { 
        int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); 
        Console.WriteLine("MySQL Library Init Failed with error code: " + lastError); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Errors regarding your configuration should be printed to the console window by the `mysql_server_init()` function.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got hospitalized right after I put a bounty up. Anyways, I just tried with null instead, but it still fails. Unfortunately all I get in my console window is my WriteLine print out that signals it failed. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @BrettPowell: Which version of mysql do you use? Could you post your my.ini file?